# Browser console showing invalid template iteration for value undefined error

Tags: lightning-layouts

I do have a code that works as expected. But when I open the console on the browser I do see this line of error.  What is it I am doing wrong here?
[image]

Here is the LWC code -

```
 <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Selected Parts" >
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="false" vertical-align="center" class="x-large">
        <template for:each={availablePartsList} for:item="part">
           <div key={part.Id}>
            <lightning-layout-item size="9" padding="horizontal-medium">
                <p>{part.Name}</p>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="3" padding="horizontal-medium">
                Test
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
 </lightning-card>
```

Comment: `availablePartsList` is undefined. Maybe just in the beginning. Add an `lwc:if` to make sure the iterator is not attempted to be rendered before the variable becomes valid.

Comment: It would help to show the JavaScript as well, but I expect @FelixvanHove hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Please avoid using screenshots since that excludes people using screen readers from answering your question and means that text is not searchable in an Internet search.

Comment: Thanks @FelixvanHove.

Comment: @PhilW Will sure keep that in mind.